# CSS malfunctioning and random errors

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get back into making websites, so I fired up Microsoft Visual Studio, and I wrote some very basic stuff. Things were going great until I messed with my CSS and expected everything to go normally. However, I got this [error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bq4R.png)

My code:

```css
body{
    background-color: #303030;
}

#Text{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/main.css" />
</head>
<body> 
    <div id="Text">
        <h1>Test Text</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

These errors appear randomly when I edit my HTML, too.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with your HTTP server. There's no way to tell what from your HTML and CSS.

Comment: Try changing your port

Answer (score 0):

If your file is not named index.html, then the server may be trying to load a non-existent default file. When an index.html file is absent (or an alternative is not specified), then a directory listing may sometimes be displayed instead. This listing may be forbidden by the server, resulting in the error.

It looks like your trying to load: `http://localhost:52794/`.

If your file is named something like `mytestpage.html`, then you'd need to access it via `http://localhost:52794/mytestpage.html`.

Or you can try again after renaming the file to `index.html`.